# Good sources for learning Markov chain Monte Carlo (MCMC)

Tags: references, markov-chain-montecarlo

Any suggestions for a good source to learn MCMC methods?

Comment: Related question: [good summaries (reviews, books) on various applications of Markov chain Monte Carlo (MCMC)](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/32325/22228)

Comment: Nice coverage of sampling methods is in Bishop https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf and MacKay https://www.inference.org.uk/itprnn/book.pdf

Answer (score 16):

For online tutorials, there are

- [A tutorial in MCMC](http://www.soton.ac.uk/%7Esks/utrecht/), by Sahut (2000)
- [Tutorial on Markov Chain Monte Carlo](http://kmh-lanl.hansonhub.com/talks/maxent00b.pdf), by Hanson (2000)
- [Markov Chain Monte Carlo for Computer Vision](http://vcla.stat.ucla.edu/old/MCMC/MCMC_tutorial/Lect1_MCMC_Intro.pdf), by Zhu et al. (2005)
- [Introduction to Markov Chain Monte Carlo simulations and their statistical analysis](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0410490.pdf), by Berg (2004).
- [A Tutorial on Markov Chain Monte-Carlo and Bayesian Modeling](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3759243) by Martin B. Haugh (2021).

[Practical Markov Chain Monte Carlo](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-7/issue-4/Practical-Markov-Chain-Monte-Carlo/10.1214/ss/1177011137.full), by Geyer (*Stat. Science*, 1992), is also a good starting point, and you can look at the [MCMCpack](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MCMCpack/index.html) or [mcmc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mcmc/) R packages for illustrations.

Comment: fyi : 2nd two links in the list are broken

Answer (score 9):

I haven't read it (yet), but if you're into R, there is Christian P. Robert's and George Casella's book:
[Introducing Monte Carlo Methods with R (Use R)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441915753)

I know of it from following his (very good) [blog](http://xianblog.wordpress.com/)

Comment: This book doesn't go in depth into MCMC. It actually have a page on it and skip MCMC theory in its entirety to go into Metropolist hashing.

Comment: While you are 100% entitled to your own opinion on our book, I beg to disagree with the notion that we do not go in depth into MCMC there. Judging from the question I do not think the OP was asking for the deep theory of MCMC algorithms (which is somehow covered in our earlier book).

Answer (score 6):

[Gilks W.R., Richardson S., Spiegelhalter D.J. *Markov Chain Monte Carlo in Practice*. Chapman & Hall/CRC, 1996.](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=TRXrMWY_i2IC)
A relative oldie now, but still a goodie.

Answer (score 6):

[Handbook of Markov Chain Monte Carlo, Steve Brooks, Andrew Gelman, Galin Jones and Xiao-Li Meng, eds. 2011 CRC Press.](http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781420079418;jsessionid=AYSwK8euwh4-aVy7BXE2wQ%2a%2a)

[Chapter 4](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/GelmanMCMCchapter4.pdf), 'Inference from simulations and monitoring convergence' by Gelman and Shirley, is available online.

Comment: Looks set to kick Gilks, Richardson & Spiegelhalter (1996) into the long grass when that comes it in May.

Answer (score 4):

[Dani Gamerman & Hedibert F. Lopes. *Markov Chain Monte Carlo: Stochastic Simulation for Bayesian Inference* (2nd ed.). Boca Raton, FL: Champan & Hall/CRC, 2006. 344 pp. ISBN 0-412-81820-5](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yPvECi_L3bwC).

-- a more recently updated book than Gilks, Richardson & Spiegelhalter. I haven't read it myself, but it was well [reviewed in *Technometrics* in 2008](http://pubs.amstat.org/doi/abs/10.1198/tech.2008.s542), and the first edition also got a good [review in *The Statistician*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2988381) back in 1998.

Answer (score 4):

Another classic position (as accompanied to already mentioned *Introducing Monte Carlo Methods with R*):

[Monte Carlo Statistical Methods](http://www.springer.com/statistics/statistical+theory+and+methods/book/978-0-387-21239-5) by Robert and Casella (2004)

in the *Use R!* series there is also:

[Introduction to Probability Simulation and Gibbs Sampling with R](http://www.springer.com/statistics/statistical+theory+and+methods/book/978-0-387-40273-4) by Suess and Trumbo (2010)

Answer (score 0):

The text I have found most accessible is [Bayesian Cognitive Modeling: A Practical Course](http://bayesmodels.com/).  Very clear exposition.  The book has great examples in BUGS, and they have been ported to Stan on its github [examples](https://github.com/stan-dev/example-models) page.