# Good summaries (reviews, books) on various applications of Markov chain Monte Carlo (MCMC)?

Tags: machine-learning, markov-chain-montecarlo, inference, references, application

Are there any good summaries (reviews, books) on various applications of Markov chain Monte Carlo (MCMC)?

I've seen [Markov Chain Monte Carlo in Practice](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412055511), but this books seems a bit old.

Are there more update books on various applications of MCMC in areas such as machine leearning, computer vision, and computational biology?

Comment: Related question: [Good sources for learning Markov chain Monte Carlo (MCMC)](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/5885/22228)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes the Handbook of MCMC is a very up-to-date collection of papers on MCMC, Also the book by Robert and Casella is a more current account than Markov Chain Monte Carlo in Practice.  But I think MCMC in Practice is really a good place to start learning the subject.
Here are amazon links to descriptions of the books I mentioned above.

[Introducing Monte Carlo Methods with R](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441915753)

[Handbook of Markov Chain Monte Carlo](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1420079417)

Answer (score 5):

I found this article to be a good review/primer on MCMC for machine learning:

[An Introduction to MCMC for Machine Learning](http://cis.temple.edu/~latecki/Courses/RobotFall07/PapersFall07/andrieu03introduction.pdf) - Andrieu, de Freitas, Doucet & Jordan (2003).

Answer (score 2):

SAS 9.3 now provides [proc mcmc](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mcmc_sect001.htm) with a detailed documentation (as usual!). No fewer than 19 examples illustrate that new bayesian procedure. Simple linear regression models, linear and non-linear mixed models, but also Cox models and many other types of analysis are covered.

Strictly speaking, this is not a book... but it is definitively a gold mine of applications ;-)