# Should I find this big parameter suspicious?

Tags: distributions, logistic, goodness-of-fit

I have some kind of disagreement with a groupmate. We have some data, and we have to fit a loglogistic distribution. Our highest data point is less than 14,000,000. The average of our data is 231,316.865 and standard deviation is 1,118,713.553.

E used Excel to estimate parameters of a loglogistic distribution (via MLE) and came up with shape=0.560983285656052, scale=4010.69503243576. I did it in R and came up with shape=1.667393, scale=8.294636.

I used Kolmogorov-Smirnov, and R didn't give a reason to say mine wasn't a good fit.

```
ks.test(b, "pllog", shape=1.667393, scale=8.294636)
        One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
data:  b
D = 0.0377, **p-value = 0.8836**
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
Warning message:
In ks.test(b, "pllog", shape = 1.667393, scale = 8.294636) :
  ties should not be present for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
```

As for h parameters...

```
ks.test(b, "pllog", shape=0.560983285656052, scale=4010.69503243576)
        One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
data:  b
D = 1, **p-value < 2.2e-16**
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
Warning message:
In ks.test(b, "pllog", shape = 0.560983285656052, scale = 4010.69503243576) :
  ties should not be present for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
```

I tried simulating values and this what I got with mine.

```
rllog(20, shape=1.667393, scale=8.294636)
 [1] 1.164583e+05 5.387827e+04 2.440876e+01 5.083744e+03 1.669974e+00
 [6] 1.125328e+05 3.781694e+02 5.572336e+04 2.352123e+03 4.060668e+03
[11] 2.597518e+02 1.068868e+02 4.695207e+03 7.780321e+03 5.787856e+03
[16] 2.196655e+04 2.933098e+04 1.253264e+06 1.196900e+03 5.399473e+02
```

This is what I got using h parameters. I notice if I start using scale=30, I get numbers in the 13 digits.

```
rllog(20, shape=0.560983285656052, scale=4010.69503243576)
 [1] Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf
[20] Inf
```

Comment: Couldn't you simply generate some data (so you'd know the parameters in advance) and check how well does the two software work for them? [Simulation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135665/when-to-use-simulations/135684#135684) is a method of choice in this kind of problems.

Comment: you should do simulation the other way: first generate values from a distribution with some parameters of your choice, and *then* use both R and Excel to estimate the parameters. Next, check the difference between the estimated parameters and their real values (that you know in advance!).

Comment: For a particular data-set it's always good practice to plot the likelihood.

Comment: Please notice that $\exp(8.294636) = 4002.346$ and $\exp(0.56098)=1.752389$ shows reasonably close agreement between Excel and `R`. As always, whenever using two or more computing platforms, you need to consult their documentation to make sure you are interpreting output correctly.

Comment: @whuber: Looks like you've put your finger on it. Also $1/1.667393 = 0.5997386$.

Comment: @Tim We realized it on our own. It was pretty dumb of me. Hahaha. To be fair, our prof never emphasized different parametrizations. E even gave a quiz without specifying a distribution so we guessed the probabilities based on the pdf we thought was right.

Comment: @Scortchi same comment. hehe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $X$ has a logistic distribution with location parameter $\mu$ and scale parameter $\sigma$

$$\newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}}f(x) = \frac{\exp\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)}{\sigma \left[1+ \exp\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right]^2}$$

then $Y=\log(X)$ has a log-logistic distribution

$$f(y) = \frac{ \frac{\sigma^{-1}}{\e^\mu}\cdot \left(\frac{y}{\e^\mu}\right)^{\sigma^{-1}-1}}{\left[1 + \left(\frac{y}{\e^\mu}\right)^{\sigma^-1}\right]^2}$$

whose scale is *not* $\mu$ but $\e^\mu$. Though $\sigma$ might as well be called the shape, a common parametrization uses scale $\beta=\e^\mu$ & shape $\alpha=\sigma^{-1}$

$$f(y) = \frac{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\cdot \left(\frac{y}{\beta}\right)^{\alpha-1}}{\left[1 + \left(\frac{y}{\beta}\right)^{\alpha}\right]^2}$$

You're certainly not reporting an estimate of scale, as that also estimates the distribution median & 8.29 seems far too low. If you're reporting $\hat\mu=8.294636$ and $\hat\sigma=1.667393$, then $\hat\alpha=0.59973$ & $\hat\beta=4002.3$; remarkably close to what your colleague is reporting.<sup>†</sup>

Plotting the likelihood is always a good idea. Here it is from a simulated sample, but you can use the real one:

[image: contour plot of log-likelihood]
[image: wire-frame plot of log-likelihood]

You can see at a glance whether the maximum found by an algorithm is plausible.

† This is more detective work than Statistics (you should've included details in the question), but `findFn` (from the `sos` package) suggests that the `pllog` function you're using is from the `FAdist` package. The documentation is rather vague:—

> If Y is a random variable distributed according to a logistic
>   distribution (with location and scale parameters), then $X = exp(Y)$
>   has a log-logistic distribution with shape and scale parameters
>   corresponding to the scale and location parameteres [sic] of Y,
>   respectively.

"Corresponding to" gives the impression of having been chosen to avoid "equal to", but the code for `pllog` is

```
function (q, shape = 1, scale = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE) 
    {
        Fx <- plogis(log(q), location = scale, scale = shape)
        if (!lower.tail) 
        Fx <- 1 - Fx
        if (log.p) 
        Fx <- log(Fx)
        return(Fx)
    }
```

So if you're using the related `dllog` density function

```
function (x, shape = 1, scale = 1, log = FALSE) 
{
    fx <- dlogis(log(x), location = scale, scale = shape, log = FALSE)/x
    if (log) 
        return(log(fx))
    else return(fx)
}
```

to find the maximum-likelihood it will indeed be $\hat\mu$ & $\hat\sigma$ you're calling "scale" & "shape". More tenuously, if your colleague doesn't have a handbook of distributions sitting on their desk, they may well have have looked up the log-logistic distribution in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-logistic_distribution), where it's parametrized with shape $\alpha$ & scale $\beta$. Mystery solved!

Comment: We realized it on our own. It was pretty dumb of me. Hahaha. To be fair, our prof never emphasized different parametrizations. E even gave a quiz without specifying a distribution so we guessed the probabilities based on the pdf we thought was right.