# Estimate MLE with Metropolis-Hastings algorithm

Tags: maximum-likelihood, markov-chain-montecarlo, poisson-regression, metropolis-hastings

I am learning now about the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm. I want to understand better how we can use and apply this algorithm.
For example, consider a [Poisson regression model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression).

So the probability mass function is given by $$p(y | x;\theta) = \frac{e^{-\lambda } \lambda^y}{y!}$$
where

$$\lambda := E[y|x] = e^{\theta x}.$$

If I am correct, we can approximate the maximum likelihood estimator for $\theta$ with a Monte Carlo procedure like the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, right?

My question is: how can we do this? What will be the proposal distribution $q(x,y)$? What do we know if we have the transition and acceptance probabilities? How does this help to find the MLE for $\theta$?

I am not looking for a complete solution, but more a description of how we can approximate the MLE for this model.

Comment: Metropolis-Hastings is not typically used to find maximum likelihood estimates - are you sure you are asking about that?

Answer (score 2):

The [MCMC algorithms](http://twiecki.github.io/blog/2015/11/10/mcmc-sampling/) are used to simulate from a given target distribution and not to be confused with stochastic optimisation algorithms such as the [simulated annealing algorithm](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9783319411910-c2.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1579890-p180080441) or the [Robbins-Monro algorithm](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177729586). Both groups of algorithms used Markov chains to reach their goal, but the theories behind them differ.

I suggest you read [some introduction to the topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/5885/7224), either on-line or in a [textbook](http://www.dme.ufrj.br/mcmc/).